# Third party cookies and facebook app inside an iframe, getUser fails

Tags: php, facebook

I have this problem that is driving me crazy, I hope it will help also anybody that got to my point.

After reading a lot, apparently all the "hacks" of the past (including the p3p headers) do not work anymore on safari after the next update, so I rewrote everything to append a session id inside a GET, all is fine, apart that apparently without third party cookies facebook do not work anymore:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
        var_dump($user);
```

This returns the expected result with third party cookies activated, while returns int(0) without cookies activated, why?

Is there a workaround for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Turn off cookies in the FB.init / new Facebook class, and record the access token instead. (getAccessToken). Pass that to your iFrame and use setAccessToken to set it just after initiating the Facebook class.

Comment: What do you mean pass it to your iFrame?

Comment: As the iFrame can't read cookies, you could pass via the URL that loads the iFrame. ?fb-token=TheTokenYouSaved and them read through $_GET

Comment: Yes, if it wasn't that I have no access to facebook? Maybe I'm missing something but I didn't know you could pass an access token from facebook to my url..

Comment: Have you looked at the function getAccessToken in the SDK? That's all the "access to Facebook" that you need. That gives you the access token, and setAccessToken puts it back again. Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to get the access token through php with one server call, use another method to pass that access token to the iFrame that then makes the other php call and users the access token to authorise to Facebook.

Comment: Dear @Robbie what I meant is that I do not have access to the facebook servers, I mean my application is running inside a facebook iframe, that's all I get! getAccessToken return an invalid access token as I do not get authorized since getUser returns null, that is the problem, I'll try to disable the cookies in the fb class.